# Tamper proof bootloader and firmware secure using .pem file

Tags: python-3.x, bootloader, mission-planner

**Ardupilot**

I have a cubeorange in pixhawk board I have downloaded the CubeOrange_bl.hex (bootloader) and arducopter.apj (firmware) from ardupilot. Now I need to secure the bootloader and firmware using the keys present in the `.pem` file generated by openssl.

Tamper proof the bootloader the bootloader does not allow other firmwares rather than signed firmware

Comment: What is your specific question about that project?